# how to live populate div using dynamically generated html input types

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to populate div with select option but i don't really now where to start...

i have some code to live edit the "title" of the div, but now i want to add to a specific div his option...

Here's the code that i have for now:

```
 var rooms = $("#howmanyrooms").val();
            var roomcounter = 1;
            $(".design-your-system-page-playground-container").show();
            for (var i = 0; i < rooms; i++) {
                //    $("<div class='appendeddiv'>Room-" + roomcounter++ + "</div>").appendTo(".housecontainer");
                //    $("<span>Room-" + roomcounter + " name</span>&nbsp;<input type='text' placeholder='name' id='room-" + roomcounter + "-id'></div></br>").appendTo(".infoncontainer");
                //
                $("<div class='design-your-system-page-rooms targetDiv_" + roomcounter + "'>Room-" + roomcounter + "</div>").appendTo(".design-your-system-page-house");
                $("<span>Room-" + roomcounter + " name</span>&nbsp;<input type='text' placeholder='name' id='room-" + roomcounter + "-id' class='textInput' lang='targetText_" + roomcounter + "'>&nbsp<select>Heating<option value='radiator'>Radiator</option><option value='underfloor'>Underfloor</option><option value='electric'>Electric</option></select>&nbsp;<select class='design-your-system-number-of-radiator-select'><option value='0'>0</option><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option><option value='6'>6</option><option value='7'>7</option><option value='8'>8</option><option value='9'>9</option></select>&nbsp;<span>Do you want the room to be smart (footprint) ?<input type='radio' name='smart-yes' value='smart-yes'>Yes</input>&nbsp;<input type='radio' name='smart-no' value='smart-no'>No</input></div></br>").appendTo(".design-your-system-page-edit-room-container");
                roomcounter++;
            };
            if ($('.design-your-system-page-house').find('.design-your-system-page-rooms').length) {
                $("#buttonaddrooms").hide();
            }

            $("input.textInput").on("keyup", function () {
                var target = $(this).attr("lang").replace("Text", "Div");
                $("." + target).text($(this).val());
            });
```

as you can see, when i click the button, i'll append to the parent as many child divs as the value typed into the textbox and i also create the same number of "row" containing the name and other option (two select and a radio)
i'm already able to live edit the name of the ralative div, but now i want to add to that div also the other options

here a jsfiddle to help you understand what i have and what i want:
http://jsfiddle.net/3cyST/

if is not clear please tell me.
thanks

Comment: the part of what should go next after what i can do in your fiddle still confuses me.

Comment: when you press the button, you create a grid with div.
At the bottom, you create the same number of rows with "name", "select test" "select number" and "radio button".
If you type inside the "name", you can see that the title of the div in the grid changes live...do you know how can i use the same live method to also add the option that i select on the other inputs of the row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3cyST/3/) fiddle:

i made your `target` variable global to be reusable, i also added a class for your first `select` element which is `selecting`

ive updated it and it now appends the value of your test `onchange` using:

```
 $("select.selecting").on("change", function () {
                $("." + target).append($(this).val());
            });
```

you can work for the rest now.

**EDIT**(*for the question of OP on the comment*) :

to get value of radio button i'll give you **2** ways :

in **`Javascript`** :

```
if (document.getElementById('ID_OF_RADIO').checked) {
  rate_value = document.getElementById('ID_OF_RADIO').value;
}
```

in **`jQuery`** :

```
$("input[name=RADIO_NAME]:checked").val();
```

Comment: ok, it works fine. Just a question, how can i manage the radio button? I mean, i cannot use val right?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3cyST/2/ i tryed to add your new code here, but the radio buttons doesn't work.
And also, when i paste my code into my project, i have this error on jquery:
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .
Seam like it doens't set the target for the select.selecting

Comment: ok, perfect. Any ideas about the error that i mentioned before?

Comment: it's not clear to me in what's happening in your project maybe you could post another question for that

Answer (score 0):

give the select an id, then use

```
$("#id").on("change",function(){
    console.log(this.value);
    //whatever you want to do with the value
})
```

...same for the radio buttons and other options...also note that the radio buttons shouldn't have different names:

```
<input type='radio' name='radio_{put id here}' value='yes'>Yes</input>
<input type='radio' name='radio_{put id here}' value='no'>No</input>
```

another thing for the readabillity of the code: try using a template....just put a `<noscript>` with an id in the code...use some distinctive syntax to put placeholders in it, and replace them at runtime:

HTML:

```
<noscript id="template">
    RoomName: <input type="text" id="roomName_%ROOMID%" />
    Do you want...
    <input type='radio' name='radio_%ROOMID%' value='yes'>Yes</input>
    <input type='radio' name='radio_%ROOMID%' value='no'>No</input>
</noscript>
```

JS:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rooms; i++) {
    var tplcode = $("#template").html();
    tplcode = tplcode.replaceAll("%ROOMID%",roomcounter);
    $($.pareHTML(tplcode)).appendTo(".design-your-system-page-edit-room-container");

    $("input[name='radio_"+roomcounter+"']").on("change",function(){
        console.log("user wants:" + $("input[name='radio_"+roomcounter+"'][checked]").val())
    });
    roomcounter++;
}



// these functions help replacing multiple occurances
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(find,replace){
    return this.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g'), replace);
}

//escapse all regEx chars, so the string may be used in a regEx
function escapeRegExp(str) {
    return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3cyST/4/

Comment: the only problem is that the id will be generated dynamically...how can i set and use your solution if i don't know how many "row" and ids i'll have?

Comment: when you generate the id, you put it into the code...then just use `$("#radio_"+roomcounter)` to select it (for example)

Comment: i don't really understand the code that you wrote, do you mind to update this feed adding your code?
http://jsfiddle.net/3cyST/1/

thanks a lot

Comment: chrome, but seam like the style and the html is not displayed, i can see only the text