# whats the best way to control showing and hiding multiple charts and divs in a page

Tags: javascript

I am new in javascript,i have a page consist of different Card layouts and each card has its own chart or buttons or grids,some of them should be hidden by default and some of them should be hide or visible by click,since the page is growing by more demands ,controlling these hid/e/show is becoming a nightmare,i would like you tell me whats the best way to do this?for example i have a following div which has a chart:

```
        <section  style="width:100%;margin-top:2%;"  >
             <div id="btnCurrentStatID" class="card ShowHide" style="float:right;width:20%;height:350px;display:none;">             
               <div class="wrapper">
                 <div class="containerBtns" style="width:100%;float:right" >
                 <button type="button" id="btnErrorStat" class="btnsForCrew-Common "></button>
                 <button type="button" id="btnIdle" class="btnsForCrew-Common "></button>
                 <button type="button" id="btnService" class="btnsForCrew-Common "></button>
                 <button type="button" id="btnLinkDn" class="btnsForCrew-Common"></button>
                 <button type="button" id="btnDataIn" class="btnsForCrew-Common" ></button>
                 <button type="button" id="btnrepOff" class="btnsForCrew-Common"></button>
                 </div>  
               </div>         
              </div>
                 <div id="faultStatChartID" class="card ShowHide" >
                 <div id="chart">              
                 </div>
                 </div>              
                     <div id="pieChartID" class="card ShowHide">
                     <div id="pieChart"></div>
                 </div>
            </section>

  <section style="width:100%;float:left;margin-top:3%;" id="faultStatSubGroupsSec">
    <div id="subcatNameChartSectionID" class="card" style="width:49%;float:left;display:none">
   <div class="container">
    <div id="subcatNameChart"></div>
  </div>
        </div>
    <div id="subcatErrorChartSectionID" class="card" style="width:49%;float:right;display:none">
   <div class="container">
    <div id="subcatErrorChart"></div>
       </div>
        </div>
   <div id="subCatIdnameSectionID" class="card" style="width:49%;float:left;display:none">
   <div class="container">
    <div id="subCatIdname"></div>
       </div>
        </div>
    <div id="subCatITurNameSectionID" class="card"style="width:49%;float:right;display:none">
   <div class="container">
    <div id="subCatITurName"></div>
       </div>
        </div>

    <div></div>
    <div></div>
   </section>
```

i gave it showhide class,and by default its hidden,when i click on filter button it will be visible,and other divs should be hidden,it this continues,imagine how many time i should do it and manage to control them all,

```
      $(".ShowHide").css("display", "block");
       $("#subcatNameChartSectionID").hide();
       $("#subcatErrorChartSectionID").hide();
       $("#subCatIdnameSectionID").hide();
       $("#subCatITurNameSectionID").hide();
```

Comment: as you say 'since the page is growing by more demands', i would try map the card div with some dynamic id and than reference to some specific id with some logic.  i hope it's could help ( create element and populate using dynamically generated html ) -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447271/how-to-live-populate-div-using-dynamically-generated-html-input-types

Comment: @TaioliFrancesco i really do not understand it

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way would be to use a class for hiding.

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

And a `hideable` class for accessing every item that should be able to be hidden. The class `hide` can be added to hide the element.

```
<div class="hideable">1 hideable</div>
```

jQuery offers methods for class manipulation:

```
$('.hideable').toggleClass('hide');
$('#unique4').removeClass('hide');
$('#unique5').addClass('hide');
```

Here is the full snippet code:

```js
$('.hideable').toggleClass('hide');
$('#unique4').removeClass('hide');
$('#unique5').addClass('hide');
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="unique1" class="hideable">
  1 hideable
</div>
<div id="unique2" class="hideable">
  2 hideable
</div>
<div id="unique3" class="hideable hide">
  3 hideable
</div>
<div id="unique4" class="hideable hide">
  4 hideable
</div>
<div id="unique5" class="hide">
  5 other
</div>
```